# Ubuntu freezes after login in asus k550vx

Tags: freeze

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus k550vx laptop for last 4 days...

Cpu i7-7700HQ
Graphic nVidia gtx950m
Finally install it ... But a had problem and everything goes Confusing.

First installation freezes in updates and other software page.

But i edit "try Ubuntu without ... " and add 'apci=off' and 'nomodeset' flages and problem solved.

But OS was so slow and drivers was not installed

I install drivers including NVIDIA driver.
After that reboot with shift key (goes to grab boot menu), edit *ubuntu and remove 'nomodeset' flag.
OS comes up and everything was fine.

After that I open up terminal and Write `gedit /etc/default/grab`

and here i made a mistake ...  :|

In page that comes up I remeve valu of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.

I don't remember what exactly wrote there ... 
But i think it was "apci=off   nomodeset"

I think... I should remove just 'nomodeset'
But i romove all of it's valu.

After that i update the grub with `sudo  update-grub` and reboot.

Now immediately after login system freezes.

I edit grub in boot and add 'apci=off' and 'nomodeset' flages again but it not work...